# cpp string find() doesnt work as expected - returns big junk values

Tags: c++, eclipse, string, find, std

I'm trying to find the index of a substring in another string, using find(), but getting a junk value and not std::npos if the substring is not there.

This is the Code:

> string output1 = "abcd";
>
> cout << output.find("gf") << endl;

And this is the output:

> 18446744073709551615

can this behaviour be prevented? is there another way to find the substring?

(actually i only need to find **if** the substring is contained)

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What it return is `size_t` of npos of your string because it can't find your char or text. you can do this instead:

```
std::size_t found = str.find("findme");

if (found != std::string::npos)
    std:cout << found << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "String not found" << std::endl // If not found
```

Comment: the condition is false and no output is shown - npos should be -1, as far as i know, and therefore the values differ

Comment: yes, the value is -1 but when you using `std::cout` to print it, it will show junk like you say. If you want to properly print it, use `printf("%Iu", npos)` (msvc) or `printf("%zu", npos)` for gcc

Comment: so why does the condition fail?

Comment: yes, because it can't find your text, then it not doing anything inside the `if`. You can add else if you want to add not found output